# Query similar rows with different value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table as per below.

| Sub_JS_Number | Issued_weight | Defect_type | Defect_weight | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2121830/1-001A | 7.58 | Crack | 6.43 | December |
| 2121830/1-001A | 7.58 | Crack | 6.43 | January |
| 2121830/1-001A | 7.58 | Clamping crack | 1.134 | January |
| 2122032/2-001A | 4.52 | Crack | 4.50 | January |
| 2122032/2-001A | 4.52 | Clamping crack | 2.92 | January |
| 2121880/1-001A | 7.78 | Crack | 7.78 | February |
| 2121880/1-001A | 7.78 | Crack | 7.78 | January |

I want to query out rows with same `Sub_JS_Number` and `Month` but different in `Defect_type` and the sum of the `Defect_weight` for that particular rows is greater than `Issued_weight`.

Expected Result:

| Sub_JS_Number | Issued_weight | Defect_type | Defect_weight | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2122032/2-001A | 4.52 | Crack | 4.50 | January |
| 2122032/2-001A | 4.52 | Clamping crack | 2.92 | January |

There are two `Sub_JS_Number` with the same `Month` which are *2121830/1-001A* and *2122032/2-001A*.

However only `Sub_JS_Number` *2122032/2-001A* rows are shown because sum of `Defect_weight` for those two rows exceed the `Issued_weight`.

If it is not possible, I would like to query out just rows with same `Sub_JS_Number` and `Month` but different in `Defect_type` without the aforementioned condition. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the `issued_weight` functionally dependent upon the `Sub_JS_Number`? That is to say, is it true that if two rows have the same `Sub_JS_Number`, they must have the same `Issued_weight`?

Comment: Also, I think you have contradicted yourself.. you said you wanted rows where "sum of the defect weight for that particular rows is *less than* issued_weight". But then you later said "rows are shown because sum of Defect_weight for those two rows *exceed* the Issued_weight." Do you want rows where the sum of defect weight is less than the issued weight, or vice versa?

Comment: @allmhuran yes, the issued_weight is functionally dependent upon the Sub_JS_Number. and yes if two rows have same Sub_JS_Number, they must have the same Issued_weight. I have to edit the question again since it was a mistake, i meant 'greater than'

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're after.

I use a CTE to find rows with the same `Sub_JS_Number`, and `month`. I also group by `issue_weight`, which is implied to be safe by your comment because it is depdenent upon `Sub_JS_Number`. Grouping on it allows me to compare it to the sum of `defect_weight`. I only get rows where there is more than one distinct `defect_type`.

Once I have found the `Sub_JS_Numbers` matching your conditions I just join back to the original table to get the full original rows, per your expected output.

```sql
create table #mytable
(
   sub_js_number varchar(20),
   issued_weight decimal(9,3),
   defect_type varchar(20),
   defect_weight decimal(9, 3),
   [month] varchar(20)
);

insert #mytable 
(
   sub_js_number, 
   issued_weight, 
   defect_type, 
   defect_weight, 
   [month]
)
values
   ('2121830/1-001A',  7.58,'Crack          ', 6.43  , 'December'),
   ('2121830/1-001A',  7.58,'Crack          ', 6.43  , 'January '),
   ('2121830/1-001A',  7.58,'Clamping crack ', 1.134 , 'January '),
   ('2122032/2-001A',  4.52,'Crack          ', 4.50  , 'January '),
   ('2122032/2-001A',  4.52,'Clamping crack ', 2.92  , 'January '),
   ('2121880/1-001A',  7.78,'Crack          ', 7.78  , 'February'),
   ('2121880/1-001A',  7.78,'Crack          ', 7.78  , 'January ');

with matches as
(
   select   distinct    
            sub_js_number 
   from     #mytable
   group by sub_js_number, 
            issued_weight, 
            [month]
   having   count(distinct defect_type) > 1 
            and sum(defect_weight) > issued_weight
)
select t.*
from   #mytable t
join   matches  m on m.sub_js_number = t.sub_js_number;
```